# How to optimize this or do this without a loop in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

I've got the following code, this code is supposed to give us how many data blocks of a given table doesn't have a single row. I have a time limit of 15 seconds but when I ran it first it took 103 seconds to run. I tried to optimize via eliminating the loops but I can't do it, I couldn't even come up with a solution without a loop.

```
create or replace procedure num_of_rows IS
 cnt NUMBER;
 total NUMBER;
BEGIN 
 total := 0;
 FOR rec IN (select file_id, block_id, blocks from dba_extents 
             where owner='TABLE_OWNER' and segment_name='TABLE_NAME')
 LOOP
  FOR i in 1..rec.blocks LOOP
   SELECT count(*) into cnt FROM TABLE_OWNER.TABLE_NAME 
   WHERE dbms_rowid.rowid_relative_fno(ROWID) = rec.file_id
   AND dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(ROWID) = rec.block_id+i-1;
   IF cnt = 0 THEN total := total + 1; END IF;
  END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
 dbms_output.put_line(total);
END num_of_rows;



set serveroutput on
execute num_of_rows();
```

Could you please show me ways this could be optimized?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I could, but is not the point of this that you need to think about it?

Answer (score 0):

This only scans the table once, so should be faster.

It generates each `block_id` by generating a dummy rowset for each row in `dba_extents` (`cross apply` requires Oracle 12.1), then excludes the blocks that exist in the table.

```
select count(*)
from   dba_extents x
       cross apply (select x.block_id + rownum - 1 as block_id from dual connect by rownum <= x.blocks) x2
where  owner = 'TABLE_OWNER'
and    segment_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
and    ( x.relative_fno, x2.block_id )
       not in
       ( select distinct dbms_rowid.rowid_relative_fno(rowid) as rowid_relative_fno
              , dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) as rowid_block_number
         from  table_owner.table_name );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are allowed for dynamic SQL, go for it. You can achieve with re-writing the 2FORLOOP-2SELECT into single query which will improve the performance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please provide an example of the rewrite so the OP and others can see what you mean.  See here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm not aloowed to use dynamic sql